# Any way of "multiplying" MySql records to test a large db on server?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, search

I have several mysql tables in a database.

Currently I am doing finishing test on my website, and one is to test a heavy db to see how much this affects performance (searching).

The website is a classifieds website.
It would take a very long time for me to insert one classified at a time to reach a significant nr.

**So I wonder, is there any way of multiplying records in MySql, preferrably with phpMyAdmin?**

Lets say I already have 20 finished records, and just multiply them several times and I get a large db in no time. Possible?

You should know that my tables have foreign keys and other relations...

If you need more input let me know...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into mytable ( col1, col2, col3... )
select col1, col2, col3 from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mytable
```

There's no need to list the fields individually, as you know the structure is going to be the same.

Comment: The only potential problem would be any auto-incrementing identity field.